# Is it possible to modify a Crystal Report chart using ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

I have a Crystal Report which contains a subreport. Inside that subreport are several charts. I would like to be able to programmatically modify some of the charts' properties (title, legend font size, etc.) in my C# code. Is this possible?

I am using Visual Studio 2010 with Crstal Reports for Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 2):

I found what I thought was the solution for me 
[here](http://scn.sap.com/thread/1728292).

Unfortunately, however, the `ReportClientDocument` object used to access the chart cannot come from a subreport, so I think I am out of luck.

In any event I am providing the link above as it may help others whose charts are not in subreports...